# Eigenvalues of symetric matrix and eigenvalues of symetric matrix plus rank one matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian

If $M$ is a symetric matrix with eigenvalues $m_1 \geq m_2 ... \geq m_n$ is there any connection between those eigenvalues and the eigenvalues $m'_1 \geq m'_2 ... \geq m'_n$ of the matrix $M' = M + xx^T$ ?
I think that it has to be that: $m'_i \geq m_{i+1} \leq m'_{i+1}$ ? Am I right? How it can be proofed?

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to diagonal plus rank one. The latter admits sort of an explicit solution in the sense that one can obtain an explicit (transcendental) equation for the eigenvalues. Look for diagonal plus rank one. However if all you need is this interlacing property there should be already results out there. Look for interlacing property. It's also related to the minmax principle.

Comment: @cbdes You are correct. This can be proved using [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl's_inequality_about_perturbation).